# AWS Glue error java.io.UncheckedIOException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am using pyspark logic to perform data computation in AWS Glue, I am getting an error:

```
23/03/22 09:47:01 ERROR StreamGobbler: 
Exception reading inputstream of analyzer process java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Any suggestions on how do we resolve this in AWS Glue.

The following is my data processing logic:

```
def classify_hsp_supported_and_hsp_non_supported(self, refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df, refine_resolver_group_ishspNotRelated_df):
    refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df_splitted_view = refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df.select(
                                                        "manager",
                                                         explode(split(col("resolverGroup"), "[|]")).alias("resolverGroup")
                                                        )
    RefineResolverGroupData.print_dataframe(refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df_splitted_view,
                                            "refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df_splitted_view")

    flatten_resolver_group_config_df = self.flatten_resolver_group_config_dataframe()
    dfWithNonSupported = refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df_splitted_view.join(
        flatten_resolver_group_config_df.drop("nonhspSupportedResolverGroups"),
        refine_resolver_group_ishspRelated_df_splitted_view.resolverGroup == flatten_resolver_group_config_df.hspSupportedResolverGroups,
        "left"
    )
    dfWithSupportedAndNonSupported = dfWithNonSupported.join(
        flatten_resolver_group_config_df.drop("hspSupportedResolverGroups"),
        dfWithNonSupported.resolverGroup == flatten_resolver_group_config_df.nonhspSupportedResolverGroups, "left"
    )

    refine_resolver_group_df = dfWithSupportedAndNonSupported.groupBy("Manager").agg(
        collect_list("resolverGroup").alias("resolverGroup"),
        collect_list("hspSupportedResolverGroups").alias("hspSupportedResolverGroups"),
        collect_list("nonhspSupportedResolverGroups").alias("nonhspSupportedResolverGroups"),
    )
    refine_resolver_group_df = refine_resolver_group_df.withColumn("ishspRelated", lit("t"))
    refine_resolver_group_df = refine_resolver_group_df.withColumn("resolverGroup",
                                                                   concat_ws("|", col("resolverGroup")))
    refine_resolver_group_df = refine_resolver_group_df.withColumn("hspSupportedResolverGroups",
                                                                   concat_ws("|", col("hspSupportedResolverGroups")))
    refine_resolver_group_df = refine_resolver_group_df.withColumn("nonhspSupportedResolverGroups",
                                                                   concat_ws("|", col("nonhspSupportedResolverGroups")))

    refine_resolver_group_df = refine_resolver_group_df.select("Manager", "resolverGroup", "ishspRelated",
                                                               "hspSupportedResolverGroups",
                                                               "nonhspSupportedResolverGroups")

    RefineResolverGroupData.print_dataframe(refine_resolver_group_df, "refine_resolver_group_df")
    union_dataset_df = RefineResolverGroupData.dataset_union(refine_resolver_group_df, refine_resolver_group_ishspNotRelated_df)
    refine_data_published = self.publish_data_to_s3(union_dataset_df)
    if not refine_data_published:
        logger.error("Something went wrong with Employee Hierarchy Job. Please check resolver group refining logic")
        raise RuntimeError("Refine Resolver Group data job failed")

    logger.info("Resolver Group refine data processing is successfully completed {}".format(run_date))
```

Comment: You can ignore this error. It comes after finishing the whole Glue script and closing the connection with the server (Ec2s).

Comment: Please share official documentation if this error is expected, can glue team confirm the same as mentioned above by Rishabh that it is expected and can be ignored.